# how to return/work/process a LINQ-Query List result?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, foreach, return

```
My class:
    public class Definitions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I managed this so far:
If I understand correctly my result
 Definitions.Name ..and
 Definitions.Id

are all saved in a List obejct!?
(Thats what I want to get, and it works, since I can access it with foreach)

```
    public static void ReadDefinitions2()
    {
        var files = (from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Settings.NotecadddyDefinitionsFolder)
                     select new Definitions 
                     {
                         Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                         Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First()
                     }).ToList();

        foreach (Definitions f in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
        }
    }
```

++1. Question:
where comes the f from???
I got the snippet partially from the net,...so I don't really understand it 100%.

++2.Question:
why I cannot use

```
    Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).Take(1)
```

instead of:

```
    Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First()
```

Error:
Der Typ "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" kann nicht implizit in "string" konvertiert werden.
I know First is already optimal, but I just wanna understand, since for me its the same!? take 1=!take first????

++3.Question: What is my List Object/variabel thing?
Definitions f or files?

I did some performance test with 3.000 files a 25KB~130ms...inside VS.(debug/release=same)
seems good.
Now when I don't add .ToList(); and make NO "foreach", then time =0ms.
(If I understand correctly, it basicly does nothing, since there is no result)
-with ".ToList()" its always 130ms, no matter if foreach or no.

So what is excactly my result/variable/List? 
what does the .ToList() do, since I can process my List anyway with foreach?

++4.Question:(related)

Do I have a object Definitions f.Name AND
                   Definitions f.Id 
in some kind of array/list?

++5.Question:
How can I return it to my mainprogram?
I will use this List all the time. It's the only INSTANCE of that object/class I need.

Tried many things..nothing works:
return xxxx;??
and how to start the method? please full example like:

```
   static void Main()
    {
    Definitions=ReadDefinitions2();
    }

public static ReadDefinitions2()
{
return Definitions Object(Name and ID):
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I will try explaining each question at a time.

> Question: where comes the f from??? I got the snippet from the
>   net,...so I dont really understand it.

files in this case is a `List` of `Definitions`, to access each Definitions in the List you will have to loop through items, `f` is variable/reference that points to Definitions.

> Question : why I cannot use   `Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).Take(1)`

`First()` returns single/one `Definitions` where as `Take` returns a `IEnumerable`, which is why you see an error.  You can do this `Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).Take(1).First()`

> Question :What is my List Object/variabel thing? Definitions f or files?

`Definitions`, Your previous `Linq` query constructing `Definitions` (`select new Definitions`)

Regarding the performance, in first case you are creating an `Enumeration` not the physical `List` that's why you notice `0ms`.

> Question: Do I have a object Definitions f.Name AND Definitions f.Id
>   in some kind of array/list?

I believe `Defintions` is user defined type, you might have it in your code (not sure as it is in Question).

> Question: How can I return it to my mainprogram? I will use this List
>   all the time. It's the only INSTANCE of that object/class I need.

Modify method signature to return `List<Definitions>` and return value to caller.

```
public static List<Definitions> ReadDefinitions2()
{
    var files = (from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Settings.NotecadddyDefinitionsFolder)
                 select new Definitions 
                 {
                     Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                     Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First()
                 }).ToList();

    foreach (Definitions f in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Now in `Main` method

```
static void Main()
{
   var definitions=ReadDefinitions2();
   // place your logic
}
```

Comment: woow thx alooot. I re-read the part of enumerations on MSDN and now I think I try to understand it :)))

Comment: ups.....you cannot hit enter :(     ok I have access now to it in main:  Console.WriteLine(definitions);   but how to access the single values Name and ID?  Console.WriteLine(definitions);                                   foreach (Definitions in definitions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
            }                                        doesn't work!  but I am close probably ;)

Comment: use this... `foreach (Definitions d in definitions) { Console.WriteLine(d.Name); Console.WriteLine(d.Id); } `

Comment: jaaaaaaaaaaaaaa :))) great....I think I got a basic understanding and minimal toolset to go on :)))                      but there it is again this mysterious "d".  as I understand it is a temporal variable which has to be the same first letter then the Datatype, in my case the Custom class Definitions.  In the MSDN example they are not shown. When to use them and when not?

Comment: You are correct, it is temporary variable. It can be any character or string need not to be just first character :-)